# Invalid column name error from SQL generated by EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Below you can see the SQL should join by using [ClassId1] instead of [Class1_ClassId] since the latter doesn't exist.

I'm pretty sure I can use Fluent API to correct this but not sure what methods.

*Generated SQL*

```
SELECT ...
FROM [dbo].[School] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[SchoolId] = [Extent2].[SchoolId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Class] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Class1_ClassId] = [Extent3].[ClassId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Class] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[Class2_ClassId] = [Extent4].[ClassId]
WHERE ...
```

*Tables*

```
School
- SchoolId
- Name
- StudentId

Student
- StudentId
- Name
- Class1Id
- Class2Id

Class
- ClassId
- Name
```

*Models*

```
public class School
{
    [Required]
    public long SchoolId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long StudentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [Required]
    public long StudentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long ClassId1 { get; set; }

    public long? ClassId2 { get; set; }

    public virtual Class Class1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Class Class2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    [Required]
    public long ClassId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Required]
public long ClassId1 { get; set; }

public long? ClassId2 { get; set; }

public virtual Class Class1 { get; set; }
public virtual Class Class2 { get; set; }
```

You haven't setup any relationship between these properties. Since you haven't defined foreign key columns for `Class1` or `Class2`, it'll create them for you: `Class1_ClassId` and `Class2_ClassId`. Creating a migration *should* create those columns for you; but you'd end up with duplicates (`Class1Id` and `Class1_ClassId` for example).

I *believe* EntityFramework will resolve relationships between properties if the name ends with `Id`. Which means your setup should be:

```
[Required]
public long Class1Id { get; set; }

public long? Class2Id { get; set; }

public virtual Class Class1 { get; set; }
public virtual Class Class2 { get; set; }
```

However, I find it's better to be explicit - purely for readability and to ensure EF doesn't try to get too smart. I'd write it like this:

```
[Required]
public long ClassId1 { get; set; }

public long? ClassId2 { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ClassId1")]
public virtual Class Class1 { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ClassId2")]
public virtual Class Class2 { get; set; }
```

This should properly setup your foreign key relationships in the database.

Comment: Exactly what I was missing! Thanks for the help and quick response. One last follow up question: I'm guessing I didn't need these on the other virtual properties because EF was able to figure them out on it's own?

Comment: @user3953989 It depends how you set up the other properties. I believe it's smart enough to realise that `ForeignRow` and `ForeignRowId` are related; but to be honest, I haven't worked with EF in a while, and an unsure on the exact rules. I tend to be explicit on all foreign keys, regardless of whether or not EF can figure it out automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think Entity Framework constructed this SQL from your linq, because the relations between the classes in your model are unclear.

According to your model a `School` has only one `Student`, a `Student` doesn't know which `School` he attends, and is obliged to have one `Class`, and possibly a second one. A `class` does not know in which `School` it is, nor which `Students` are in the `Class`.

**Are you sure about your model?**

I'd gather that a `School` would have zero or more `Students`. A `School` also has zero or more `Classes`. Each `class` is a class in a `School`.

In database terms this is a typical one-to-many relationship. See [Entity Framework Configure One-to-Many Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Furthermore a `Student` attends zero or more `Classes`, a `Class` has one or more `Students`.

In database terms this is a typical many-to-many relationship. See: [Entity Framework configure many-to-many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

These articles also describe schools, students and couses. Summarized the class definitions ought to be:

```
class School
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // a School has many Students:
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
    // a School has many Classes:
    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // A student belongs to one School via Foreign Key
    public int SchoolId {get; set;}
    public virtual School School {get; set;}

    // A student attends many classes
    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes {get; set;}
    ...
}

class Class
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // a class belongs to one School via foreign key:
    public int SchoolId {get; set;}
    public virtual School School {get; set;}

    // a class has many Students
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

After this the DbContext will be as follows:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<School> Schools {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Class> Classes {get; set;}
}
```

If you model it like this, entity framework will automatically recognize the one-to-many relationships between School and Students, and create proper foreign keys for it. It will also recognize the many-to-many relationship between Students and Classes. It will even create a table for the many-to-many, which you won't need in your LINQ queries.

[Entity Framework uses default conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) If you follow them, you won't need to tell the model about Table names and column names, about primary keys and foreign keys etc.

**Back to your question**

You want to tell your model that it should use a certain column name for a property instead of the column name it constructed from your class relations.

This can be done using Data Annotations within your class, or using Fluent API within your DbContext. I prefer using Fluent Api, because it allows you to use the same classes in different database structures without having to change the classes. If you want different table names, or different names for primary keys, different precision for decimals, etc, all you have to do is create a new DbContext. You don't have to change your classes, users of your classes won't notice the changes.

[Fluent API is described here.](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx)

In you case: specify a table name instead of the default table name.

In my example, A `Class` would be put in table `Classs`, while of course you'd want it in table `Classes`:

```
 class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<School> Schools {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Class> Classes {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Entity Class should be put in table Classes
        modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().ToTable("Classes");

        // property Student.ClassId in column "ClassId1"
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()               // from class Student
            .Property(student => student.ClassId)    // take property ClassId
            .HasColumnName("ClassId1");              // give it the column name "ClassId1"

    }
}
```